# From staging to existing production Laravel application

Tags: database, laravel, production, staging

Hey folks and moderators,

Let’s say I have deployed a Laravel application on production server and how do I modify and update the application without affecting production data?

Assumed that I wanted to release the next version of the application with additional few columns for table Users.

The question is should I clone database from live to staging?
What is the right way to modify staging application and deploy to production without affecting the production database even though there are additional tables/columns from staging?

Currently I running two different environments and drop production tables and import from staging. It sounds like not efficient.

Any better idea to improve from staging to production?

Thank you!

I’ve been tried to search around unfortunately it brings no luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Assumed that I wanted to release the next version of the application with additional few columns for table Users.

Yes writing a new migration like this:

```php
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('email');  // Adding
    $table->string('name', 50)->change();  //Changing
```

});

Thats for adding, for changing type, renaming and dropping columns, you will also have to install: `composer require doctrine/dbal`

See more info at the docs:https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#creating-columns

> The question is should I clone database from live to staging? What is the right way to modify staging application and deploy to production without affecting the production database even though there are additional tables/columns from staging?
>
> ...
>
> Any better idea to improve from staging to production?

I'm assuming you are using Git. A single server, and that you can put down your app for a while, maybe do the update when the less users are using the system.

1. Push to repository
2. ssh to production server
3. php artisan down --message="Your Awesome Message About your update" --retry=60
4. BACK UP YOUR DATABASE (Just in case something goes wrong!)
5. git pull
6. composer update
7. php artisan migrate
8. php artisan up

Just be sure that your migrations always have rollbacks!

You can make another back/dump after migrating if you want to use real data at staging or development.